# Why can I not assign the concatenation of constant strings to a constant string?

Tags: c#, string, constants

Occasionally I want to break apart a constant string for formatting reasons, usually SQL.

```
const string SELECT_SQL = "SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM TABLE1 WHERE Field4 = ?";
```

to

```
const string SELECT_SQL = "SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 " 
                        + "FROM TABLE1 " 
                        + "WHERE Field4 = ?";
```

However the C# compiler will not allow this second form to be a constant string.  Why?

Comment: In the examples I only show string literals, but in some cases I would include other constant strings (such as a field name) that is only defined in one place.

Comment: My guess is that those aren't *actual* string constants...

Comment: I just ran the second example in .net 3.5 and it worked just fine.

Comment: I suggest you post examples that *don't* compile then, rather than ones which do...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Um, that should be fine... are you *sure* it doesn't compile?

Sample code:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    const string MyConstant = "Foo" + "Bar" + "Baz";

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyConstant);
    }
}
```

My guess is that in your *real* code you're including some non-constant expression in the concatenation.

For example, this is fine:

```
const string MyField = "Field";
const string Sql = "SELECT " + MyField + " FROM TABLE";
```

but this isn't:

```
static readonly string MyField = "Field";
const string Sql = "SELECT " + MyField + " FROM TABLE";
```

This is attempting to use a non-constant expression (`MyField`) within a constant expression declaration - and that's *not* permitted.

Comment: I was going to do that @Adam Rackis - saved me some voting points!

Comment: I tried again and it works.  I don't know what I was doing wrong before, but all my fields are `const` ...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: This is attempting to use a non-constant expression (MyField) within a constant expression declaration - and that's not permitted. Why is it not permitted?

Comment: @Sandeep: It's not permitted because a constant expression has to be computed at compile-time, which means you can't use values which are only going to be available at execution time.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I missed that "compile time computed". Thanks for your response.

Comment: Note that using chars in that way does *NOT* work. E.g. `const string S = "" + 'c' + 'c'` is not valid, while `const string S = "c" + "c"` is. And yes, I know it's an old question, but I was just stumped by that.