# How to include an enum value in a const string?

Tags: c#, string, enums, constants

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092470/why-can-i-not-assign-the-concatenation-of-constant-strings-to-a-constant-string), I know that a `const string` can be the concatenation of `const` things. Now, an enum is just a set of cont integers, isn't it ?
So why isn't it ok to do this :

```
const string blah = "blah " + MyEnum.Value1;
```

or this :

```
const string bloh = "bloh " + (int)MyEnum.Value1;
```

And how would you include an enum value in a const string ?

Real life example : when building an SQL query, I would like to have `"where status <> " + StatusEnum.Discarded`.

Comment: As a guess for why: concatenating an integer may involve culture dependency issues. Your `int.ToString()` may not be the same as my `int.ToString()`. Perhaps. Just a guess. In particular, negative numbers, maybe.

Comment: oh, right, I didn't read the question I linked very carefully. So it's not just about enums, it is actually impossible to include const integers in a const string too.

Comment: yes; `const string foo = "abc" + 1;` fails identically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a *workaround*, you can use a field initializer instead of a const, i.e.

```
static readonly string blah = "blah " + MyEnum.Value1;

static readonly string bloh = "bloh " + (int)MyEnum.Value1;
```

As for why: for the *enum* case, enum formatting is actually pretty complex, especially for the `[Flags]` case, so it makes sense to leave this to the runtime. For the `int` case, this could still potentially be affected by culture specific issues, so again: needs to be deferred until runtime. What the compiler *actually* generates is a *box* operation here, i.e. using the `string.Concat(object,object)` overload, identical to:

```
static readonly string blah = string.Concat("blah ", MyEnum.Value1);
static readonly string bloh = string.Concat("bloh ", (int)MyEnum.Value1);
```

where `string.Concat` will perform the `.ToString()`. As such, it could be argued that the following is slightly more efficient (avoids a box and a virtual call):

```
static readonly string blah = "blah " + MyEnum.Value1.ToString();
static readonly string bloh = "bloh " + ((int)MyEnum.Value1).ToString();
```

which would use `string.Concat(string,string)`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `readonly` or `static readonly` instead of `const`.

```
static readonly string blah = "blah " + MyEnum.Value1;
```

The reason MyEnum.Value1 is not treated as `const` is that a method call is required to convert the value to a string, and the result of a method call is not treated as a constant value even if the method arguments are constant.

Comment: ok for the string value, but why for the integer value of the enum ?

Comment: @Zonko, the compiled automatically calls `int32.ToString()` on the integer value to convert it to a string before it concatenates the strings.

Comment: @Albin actually, no; the compiler **boxes** and calls `string.Concat(object,object)`; *the compiler* doesn't call `.ToString()` at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, because `MyEnum.Value1` and `(int)MyEnum.Value1` are not constant `string` values. There will be an implicit conversion at the time of the assignment.

Use a `static readonly string` instead:

```
static readonly string blah = "blah " + MyEnum.Value1;
```